# Resfresh twice picturebox show Errorimage

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, c++-cli

I write a VideoBox class that show images capture from a video file or webcam using opencv this is my code in c++, i need a fixed size box so i override minimum and maximum

```
public ref class VideoBox : public System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox
{
public:
    VideoBox();
    ~VideoBox();

    bool capture()
    {
        cv::Mat cur_frame;
        bool r = maintracker.capture(cur_frame);

        if(!r) return r;

        imshow("debug window", cur_frame);
        this->Image  = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(cur_frame.cols, cur_frame.rows, cur_frame.step, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, (System::IntPtr)cur_frame.ptr());
        this->Refresh();

        return true;
    }

    ....

    virtual property System::Drawing::Size MinimumSize {
        System::Drawing::Size get() override { return m_desiredSize; } 
        void set(System::Drawing::Size) override { } 
    }
    virtual property System::Drawing::Size MaximumSize {
        System::Drawing::Size get() override { return m_desiredSize; }  
        void set(System::Drawing::Size) override { } 
    }

protected:
/*  virtual void OnPaint(System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^ pe) override
    {
        PictureBox::OnPaint(pe);
    }*/

private:
    System::Drawing::Size m_desiredSize;
};
```

and this is my c# class inherit from VideoBox

```
 public class Video : VideoBox
{
    public enum DrawMode { DRAW_H_LINE, DRAW_V_LINE, DRAW_RECT, NONE };
    public enum ShowMode { SHOW_USER_RECTS, SHOW_USER_LINES, HIDE_ALL, SHOW_ALL };

    public Video()
    {
        b_drawrect = b_drawhline = b_drawvline = false;
        lstBrush = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal, Color.Green, Color.Transparent);

        cTimer = new Timer();
        cTimer.Interval = 100; // msec for change frame in video mode
        cTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(cTimer_Tick);

        // if you uncomment this you can see your image on design mode :D            
        //setCaptureVideo();

        m_drMode = DrawMode.DRAW_RECT;
        m_userRects = new List<Rectangle>();
    }

    public void setCaptureVideo()
    { 
        ...
    }

    public void startVideo() { cTimer.Start(); }
    public void stopVideo() { cTimer.Stop(); }

    private void cTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        capture();
    }

    //protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    base.OnPaint(e);

    //    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    //    if (m_insertRect.Width > 0 && b_drawrect)
    //    {
    //        Pen mP = new Pen(Color.Green);
    //        g.DrawRectangle(mP, m_insertRect);
    //    }

    //    if (m_shMode == ShowMode.SHOW_USER_RECTS || m_shMode == ShowMode.SHOW_ALL)
    //    {
    //        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial",8 );
    //        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

    //        // Set format of string.
    //        StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
    //        if(m_userRects.Count > 0)
    //        {
    //            int c=1;
    //            foreach(Rectangle rect in m_userRects)
    //            {
    //                g.FillRectangle(lstBrush, rect);
    //                g.DrawString(c.ToString(), drawFont, drawBrush, rect.Location, drawFormat);
    //                c++;
    //            }
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (m_drMode == DrawMode.DRAW_RECT && !m_firstp.IsEmpty)
            {
                b_drawrect = true;

                float x = m_firstp.X < e.X ? m_firstp.X : e.X;
                float y = m_firstp.Y < e.Y ? m_firstp.Y : e.Y;
                float w = Math.Abs(m_firstp.X - e.X);
                float h = Math.Abs(m_firstp.Y - e.Y);

                m_insertRect = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, (int)w, (int)h);

                if (!cTimer.Enabled)
                    this.Refresh();
            }
        }

        if(m_drMode == DrawMode.DRAW_H_LINE && !m_firstp.IsEmpty)
        {
            m_hlinep = e.Location;
            b_drawhline = true;
            if(!cTimer.Enabled)
                this.Refresh();
        }
        else if (m_drMode == DrawMode.DRAW_V_LINE && !m_firstp.IsEmpty)
        {
            m_vlinep = e.Location;
            b_drawvline = true;

            if (!cTimer.Enabled)
                this.Refresh();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        if (b_drawvline)
        {
            b_drawvline = false;
            m_vlinep = e.Location;
            m_drMode = DrawMode.NONE;
        }
        else if (b_drawhline)
        {
            b_drawhline = false;
            m_hlinep = e.Location;
            m_drMode = DrawMode.NONE;
        }
        else
            m_firstp = e.Location;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        if (m_drMode == DrawMode.DRAW_RECT)
        {
            if (b_drawrect)
            {
                m_userRects.Add(m_insertRect);
                b_drawrect = false;
                if (!cTimer.Enabled)
                    this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    // private members
    private List<Rectangle> m_userRects;
    private Timer cTimer;
    private PointF m_firstp;
    private PointF m_hlinep, m_vlinep;
    private Rectangle m_insertRect;
    private bool b_drawrect, b_drawhline, b_drawvline;
    private HatchBrush lstBrush;

    private ShowMode m_shMode;
    private DrawMode m_drMode;
}
```

if i resize form so many times VideoBox show ErrorImage of picturebox

if i refresh video box when cTimer is enabled it shows ErrorImage again

imshow works without problem

where is the problem you think??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, a word of caution: opencv, being mostly RAII based, and managed c++ do not go well together.

you allocate a *local* Mat in your capture function:

```
bool capture()
{
    cv::Mat cur_frame;
    ...
```

this will release/invalidate its data pointer, once it goes out of scope (when leaving capture()) and your ImageBox is left with a invalid/dangling pointer.

so, you will have to keep cv::Mat cur_frame alive for the whole duration of your program, here it gets pretty ugly:

```
public:

    cv::Mat *cur_frame; // yep, a bloody *pointer*, as stupid managed c++ can't do RAII...

    VideoBox() 
    {
        cur_frame = new Mat();
    }
    ~VideoBox() 
    {
        delete cur_frame;
    }

    bool capture()
    {
        bool r = maintracker.capture( *cur_frame ); // deref

        if(!r) return r;

        imshow("debug window", *cur_frame);
        this->Image  = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(cur_frame->cols, cur_frame->rows, cur_frame->step, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, (System::IntPtr)cur_frame->ptr());
        this->Refresh();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, you save me a lot, i didn't notice at all, another question what you think better and safer way of converting cv Mat to Bitmap i see this link http://answers.opencv.org/question/14183/having-trouble-with-using-mat-image-in-picturebox/ and second answer seems prettier way than mine

Comment: one way or the other, you will have to keep the pixel data alive. (the 2nd answer in the link above does it by using the Bitmap's pixels to that (a deep copy)). but guess what; - you'll still have to keep bmpimg (the returned Bitmap) around.